# Display legends on Category Axis in Bar chart using Jfreechart or iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, jfreechart, ireport, bar-chart

I am creating a Bar chart using JFreeChart/iReport. Consider below example for reference:

Category Axis displays this series: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May
Every group (Eg: Jan) has 2 bars: Allocated, Unallocated.

In JFreechart/iRport it displays "Allocated" and "UnAllocated" in Legend box. But I it to get displayed on Category axis under respective bar. And below this it should display the series i.e. Jan.

Is it possible with Jfreechart/iReport?

Any help on this appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using GroupedStackedBarRenderer. Below is the link for reference.

http://jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/GroupedStackedBarRenderer.html